# Getting preview for an uploaded file in ACF before save

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am trying to get the value of a file after upload to preview it on the 'jersey' on this page:

https://sublimatedhockeyjerseys.com/jersey-customizer/

I have tried a few things but nothing seems to work. I am using ACF Pro and the ACF Extended to build the form. When I get the value it has what ACF will load with it for accessing it but since this is a 'preview' I don't want to save.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

I have tried the acf/load_attachment but it doesn't seem to work

I have gotten something out of this:
https://github.com/Hube2/acf-filters-and-functions/blob/master/render-image-in-editor.php
but not what I wanted.

I have gotten text like in the demo here to work but don't quite understand how it can be used for an image.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-render_field/